# Extract directory from a file path (Android Java)

Tags: android, path, directory

I want to extract the directory part of a file path in Android. I know I can use

```
File file=new File(path);
String dir=file.getParent();
```

But I am not sure if this may introduce unnecessary overhead.Is there a more straight way?

Comment: What do you mean by overhead? Are you intending to run this snippet of code some million times in a loop?

Comment: I am loading all the image files in the device with a cursor and from them deduct the directories containing images. I was wondering if the File object could introduce some media access or unnecessary initialization steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after your comment I get what you mean. Just look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/File.java#File.getParent%28%29) (this is from OpenJDK, but I doubt Android will be too different). So, no overhead because of seeking or media access.

```
public String getParent() {
    int index = path.lastIndexOf(separatorChar);
    if (index < prefixLength) {
        if ((prefixLength > 0) && (path.length() > prefixLength))
            return path.substring(0, prefixLength);
        return null;
    }
    return path.substring(0, index);
}
```